# Counting selected checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, count, smart-table

I'm having  a hard time counting selected checkboxes in my application. I've tried following along some other stack overflow questions but no dice yet...if you guys have any experience with counting checkboxes, some help would be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="document-table" st-table="documents" st-safe-src="yourDisplayedCollection" class="table">
         <div>Total checked: ({{selectedCounter}})</div>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <st-select-all all="yourDisplayedCollection"></st-select-all>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="document in documents">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="document.isSelected"/></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

.controller('DocumentsController', /** @ngInject */ function ($scope, restData, dateFormats, documents) {

```
  $scope.dateFormat = dateFormats.angularDateFilter;
  $scope.documents = documents.resultBag[0].documentBag;
  $scope.yourDisplayedCollection = [].concat(documents.resultBag[0].documentBag);
  $scope.selectAll = function (selected) {
        var documents = $scope.documents;
        angular.forEach(documents, function (documents) {
            documents.selected = selected;
        });
        // Update the counter
        if(selected){
            $scope.selectedCounter = documents.length;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedCounter = 0;
        }
    };
```

EDIT:
I have a check all boxes checkbox at the top which is why i have the yourDisplayedCollection in the table as well as the ng-model="document.isSelected"

Comment: you have several problems...one being child scope of `ng-repeat`. Can those checkboxes be bound to a property of each document? Or must they be separate?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. You need to take a look at your above example and redo it so it makes more sense.

Comment: https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/multi-checkbox-directive/ hope this directive will come in handy for you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to rework a couple things if I am understanding the anticipated outcome correctly.

First(html):

```
<tr ng-repeat="document in documents">
  //Bind your model directily to the selected property in your object (document)
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="document.selected"/></td>
</tr>
```

Second:

```
$scope.selectAll = function (selected) {
    var documents = $scope.documents;
    angular.forEach(documents, function (doc) {
        if(doc.selected)
           $scope.selectedCounter +=1;
    });

};
```

This will give you a correct count everytime. Though your function naming is misleading. SelectAll should mean literally select all. To me it looks like your just counting.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is use `Array.prototype.filter()` and use length of filtered array

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="document.selected"/>
```

And for counter:

```
$scope.selectedCounter = $scope.documents.filter(function(item){
    return item.selected;
}).length;
```

Need to be aware that you are breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model`.

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope and when you use a primitive in the child scope the parent controller can't see it change

Comment: create a plunker or other sandbox demo